# AWS global configuration update conflict

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, environment-variables, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

The problem is when I feed Dynamodb config endpoint some value the AWS Key Management Service  stops working altogether.

**1. DynamoDB**

```
    const awsConfig = {
        region: process.env.REGION,
        endpoint: process.env.ENDPOINT, //this stops AWS KMS
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    };

    aws.config.update(awsConfig);
```

**2. AWS KMS**

```
    constructor() {
        this.#KEYAWS = keyAws;
        this.#region = process.env.REGION;
        this.#secretName = process.env.SECRET_NAME;
        this.#secret = process.env.ACCESS_KEY;
        this.#_AWS_KEY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID;
    }

    async #getPrivateKey() {
        this.#KEYAWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: this.#_AWS_KEY_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: this.#secret,
        });

        var client = new this.#KEYAWS.SecretsManager({
            region: this.#region,
        });
    }
```

When I comment out the `endpoint` in Dynamo config, the KMS works properly

*Note: A VPC endpoint for DynamoDB enables Amazon EC2 instances in your VPC to use their private IP addresses to access DynamoDB with no exposure to the public internet.*

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639160/13126651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because of adding `endpoint: process.env.ENDPOINT` to global configuration Object. [AWS SDK Global Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html)

I removed the endpoint option from global configuration and specifically passed it to dynamodb service `aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({endpoint: process.env.ENDPOINT})`

So, the take here is that whenever you have a conflict, exclude those options from Global Configuration.

Check this [How to set multiple aws credentials in nodejs aws-sdk module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881991/how-to-set-multiple-aws-credentials-in-nodejs-aws-sdk-module)